# Retornar "alert" se uma IF não for executada

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso verificar se um if foi executado ou não, e se não foi ele exibir um alert?

Veja o exemplo:

```
if ($newtime!=0) {
   $qryupd = "update registration set dados=" . $dadosnew . " where id=$id";
   $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $qryupd);
   if (!$result2) {
      rollback();
      echo '[{"resultado":"falhou","total_lances":"' . $bal . '","motivo":"Falha ao executar lance, por favor tente novamente! Código: LW102"}]';
      exit;
   }
}
```

Nesse exemplo ele já faz isso para a query que atualiza no DB, se não atualizar ele mostra o alert. Eu preciso fazer a mesma coisa, porém preciso que ele verifique a primeira condição IF, no caso: `if ($newtime!=0) {`

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            if ($newtime!=0) {
        $qryupd = "update registration set dados=" . $dadosnew . " where id=$id";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $qryupd);
        if (!$result2) {
            rollback();
            echo '[{"resultado":"falhou","total_lances":"' . $bal . '","motivo":"Falha ao executar lance, por favor tente novamente! Código: LW102"}]';
            exit;
        }
        }else{
    echo "newtime é igual a 0";
    echo "<script>alert('VARIAVEL $NEWTIME É IGUAL A 0')</script>;

}
```

Acho que isso vai resolver seu Problema.
Você pode usar o IF/ELSE .

```
if(condicao)
{
entrou na condição
}else{
não entrou na condição
}
```